# Windows Phone 7: How can I do something when the user clicks on an image?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I use windows phone 7, with silverlight.
I have an image on my page and I want that when the user clicks on the image an event will raise. Moreover, If it is possible I would like to know on which point of the image the user clicked.

Comment: Be aware that a finger is much larger than a pixel and so you need to allow a lot of room in your position detection to account for this difference or where you detect the touch may not be where the user was intending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this you probebly have to consider the image location relative to coordinates.. the coordinates are probebly relative to the root element.

```
<Image MouseLeftButtonUp="image_MouseLeftButtonUp"  x:Name="image" />

private void image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        string x = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender).X.ToString();
        string y = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender).y.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The WP7 Silverlight Toolkit (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) has GestureListeners where you can attach a Tap Gesture to your image and catch the event.

```
    <Image>
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener 
                    Tap="OnTap"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    </Image>
```

Comment: it also gives you the position (e.GetPosition) on the event.

Answer (score 0):

I've check all the events you can bind to an image tag, there should be one called `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` see if that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks, I checked. I used MouseLeftButtonDown and it really entered my function when i clicked on the image. However I don't find a way to get the location of the click inside the image.